# "Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found" from public php file

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have just started using Laravel and I would like to be able to access the DB class from within a php file of which is located within the public folder.

I get the **error**

> "Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found"

. The php file is accessed by an AJAX require therefore there is no routing to this file

How do I allow my php file to access this class and similar classes to this that are available in Laravel?

File Path:

**public/php/ajaxLogin.php**

```
function getPrimaryAdd($user) {
    $result = DB::table('users')
        ->join('address', 'user_address.address_id', '=', 'address.address_id')
        ->select('address.address_id', 'longitude', 'latitude')
        ->where('user_id', $user)
        ->limit(1);
}
```

Comment: You should set up a route and have your code in a controller instead. External (direct access to php-files in the public folder) won't have the Laravel framework set up or anything. It will be executed in it's own environment and won't have any connection to Laravel...

Comment: Have you tried use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` in top of the file?

Comment: Yeah just gives me another error. I don't understand where the Illuminate folder is located? "Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB' not found in /Users/user/Sites/project/public/php/ajaxLogin.php"

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't want to run the script through Laravel, but rather as a "stand alone" script? Specially since you DO want to use Laravels classes? If we know why, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: The php file is accessed by an AJAX script so its not really a user that runs this php file. Is there a way I could still implement routes?

Comment: That makes no difference at all. It's still accessed through a http request so yes, you should implement a route for it and handle it as any other request in your application.

Comment: In case you really wanna run it as a standalone script (that is probably the wrong way, see @MagnusEriksson) - `require_once 'vendor/autoloader'`, will load your typical laravel(composer) dependencies.

Comment: @Xatenev - That will make him able to autoload the DB class, but it won't be configured so he still need to bootstrap it all manually.

Answer (score -1):

use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager as DB;
it should be top of the file
you should be able to use DB

Comment: That didn't work I just get "Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager' not found in /Users/user/Sites/project/public/php/ajaxLogin.php". Also the DB class is in my alias as "'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class"